# Diodes between BMS pins

Tags: diodes, bms

What is the purpose of the three diodes in this [BQ76940](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76940.pdf)-based battery monitor schematic?

[image]

Comment: Where did the schematic come from? There are diodes shown in the data sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those diodes are in parallel with the substrate diode inside the IC. Should a wire in the string of cells open while a load is connected, current would flow in those external diodes instead of the substrate diode inside the IC, which would destroy the IC.